# Directory Listing data Source

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'm using the Directory Listing data Source to retrieve all fine in a directory but i need the directory to be dynamical

as source directory i'm using

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}\payload\${messageType}
```

but the variable is not replaced with the a value .

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Directory does not exists: C:\MyTools\GitRepo\Compliance\performance\src\test\jmeter\payload\${messageType}
```

attached also screenshot of the listing and the test plan variable
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable(s) you set on on [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level or in [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) will be available **in the runtime** only

[image]

If you want to test your Directory Listing Config in GUI mode you need to set the `messageType` property **beforehand**, for example define it in [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter). JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change.